# Nginx: Prevent non-www address from redirecting to www?

Tags: nginx, http, redirect, https

My site uses both www and non-www addresses for our site (dcturano.com). The problem I'm having is that the server is redirecting non-www traffic to www traffic. How do I prevent this?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;

    server_name dcturano.com www.dcturano.com;

    if ($scheme = http) {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Figure out what's doing it. It doesn't appear to be this bit of configuration. Check your application and any other layers you have in front of it.

Comment: Is there anything setting server_name_in_redirect to on? My understanding is that would cause this behaviour.

Comment: You should really be using two server blocks for the example in the question. I.e. one for http, which unconditionally redirects, and one for https which does not.